# How to find median of all subarrays of an array efficiently?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, big-o, median

I've been trying to solve this question, but in no way I am coming up with efficient method. Can someone help me with how to proceed with this problem?

The problem definition can be found at:
https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/daiict-summer-long-2022/challenges/median-20-1

I tried to think in terms of sorting followed by frequency count of Mid-values but that would disturb the original subarray structure and thereby altering the Mid-Value. So I need to spend at least O(N<sup>2</sup>logN) time and that's too slow!

May be this problem can be very standard, that I can't find out for reference. I tried my best to find any similar question or some out-of-the-box technique, that I haven't come across but couldn't found anything useful for the problem :(

Comment: Picture an infinite stream of values: how would you come up with the median of the last 999 elements in turn? Try to use that mechanism here.

Answer (score 1):

This is solvable in time `O(n log(n))`.  I'll just get you started.

The key is to find a way to, given `x`, count how many mid-values are below, at, or above `x`.  You don't want to find what they are, just count them.

For this you'll need to track a lot.

```
by whether the interval is odd/even in length
    by whether the median is below/at/above the wanted
        by whether the median is in the interval
            queue of count of open intervals with median `i` away
            total in queue
            total counted so far
```

But the point is that this is a fixed number of pieces of data.  And for each element of the array that we see we can update each one in time `O(1)`.  (You do have to get the logic just right.)  So the total time is `O(n)` to do this in one pass.

Armed with this piece, we can do the following.

1. sort the values
2. do a binary search for the median mid.

Note, I am assuming that values are distinct.  If they aren't, we can adjust them slightly so that they are distinct, find the answer, then undo the adjustment to get the answer.

In Python that adjustment is as simple as replacing `value` with `adjusted_value = (value, position_in_array)`. And the inverse is `value = adjusted_value[0]`.